# Loading a UIScrollView like a UiTableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

Is there a way to load a UIScrollView in a similar way to how a UITableView is loaded - in other words, only load the visible 'cells'?

For my example I have a large scroll view which can be scrolled in any direction. Inside that are 'cells' which I add to the scroll view using code. The cells consist of data gathered from json feeds (one feed per cell). I would like to only load the feeds for the visible cells, and then cache the ones already loaded, so they don't need to be reloaded.

Is there a good method of doing this? Or is there another direction I should be taking to get this result?

A couple of answers have suggested a tiling approach, but I'm not sure that tiling is quite the right approach, since the whole cell needs to be loaded when part of it is visible. Another approach which google hints at is putting a UITableView within a UIScrollView, but I've yet to try this.

```
         ——————————----------------------
         |        |                     |  < a 'cell' row in the scrollview
         | - - - -| - - - - - - - - - - |
screen > |        |                     |
         |        |                     |
         ——————————                     |
         |                              |  < whole of scrollable area
         |                              |
         |                              |
         |                              |
         --------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you seen the endless scrollview? What they do to create it is to add content in the direction the user is scrolling. When the user reaches a specific point it moves everything back to the center of the scrollview.

Comment: Why do you have a problem with "the whole cell needs to be loaded when part of it is visible"? - this is exactly how UITableView works, which is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing "tiling."

Take a look at [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) - it demonstrates an approach to tiling.

Comment: Is that approach appropriate? It seems more for pictures. My cells are just like large table view cells which extend horizontally past the edges of the screen.

Comment: The content can be whatever you want - the most important part of the code is how you implement -layoutSubviews, which is content independent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CATiledLayer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/catiledlayer

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html