# Load More Data at the end of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'd like to implement a feed in iOS 7 that is only pulling new data if it appears the user has a chance of viewing it. I know `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` that does this well, but I can't get the cells to behave the way I'd like - I'd like it to look similar to facebook or twitter's newsfeed where you can reload by pulling down and load more by hitting the bottom.

I've seen other questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220055/loading-a-uiscrollview-like-a-uitableview) but I'm looking for vertical scrolling only, with absolutely no horizontal movement. I'd like to use a method calling (for example) `nextTenPostsFromIndex:` that instantiates from zero, and applies to whatever index was the last on the screen if hitting the bottom.

My question: Is the best way to go about this to create a `UIScrollView`, place a subview inside of it, and programmatically space them on the available scrollview space, and apply the same drawing methods again with repopulated data if `nextTenPostsFromIndex` is called or `checkForNewPosts` (if pulling down from the top)? Would this be a reasonable way to implement Facebook's iOS7 newsfeed, or others like it?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**. You really ought to use `UITableView` for things like this. You can use a custom cell or whatever you want. If it helps you, also know that since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, you can do anything you would normally do with a scrollview, including assigning a delegate which acts based on the current position when scrolling.